# React-navigation in native app clicking on back button returns to wrong screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am building a native app with React-native and am using React-navigation for the navigation. On the HomeScreen I have a list of posts. Clicking into a post and back works great. However, the user can add a post to the Favourites list. When the user goes to the FavScreen to view the list of favourite posts and clicks into a post, the Back button returns the user to the HomeScreen. Obviously it should return the user to the FavScreen.
Here is my code:

```
export const Navigation = StackNavigator({
    Home: { // List of all posts
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'POSTS',
        }
    },  
    Post: { // Single post screen
        screen: PostDetailsScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            title: navigation.state.params.postDetails.title,
        })
    },
});
export const TabsNavigation = TabNavigator({
    Home: { // List of posts tab
        screen: Navigation,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'POSTS',
        }
    },
    Fav: { // List of all favourite posts tab
        screen: PostsFavScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'FAVOURITES',
        }
    }   
});
```

I need help to find a way to return to the FavScreen when clicking back from a post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the back button I used react-native-back-button and CTRL-C CTRL-V the example. It's working smoothly !

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-back-button

EDIT : back-button is deprecated, use BackHandler instead ! =)

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/backhandler.html

Comment: I have not tested this app on Android yet, so I don't know if there is a need for this.

Comment: If you don't want to use it on Android, no need for this yeah

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive on this but it could be because the post screen is defined in the stack navigator that is used in the Home tab. So when you go from favorite to post, you're switching to the home tab. Then when you press back the StackNavigator is picking up that event and bringing you back to the root of the stack navigator (which would be the HomeScreen).

Though this is a bit of duplicate code, a solution to this issue could be to create a new StackNavigator for the Favorite screen as well, like so:

```
export const Navigation = StackNavigator({
    Home: { // List of all posts
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'POSTS',
        }
    },  
    Post: { // Single post screen
        screen: PostDetailsScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            title: navigation.state.params.postDetails.title,
        })
    },
});

export const FavNavigation = StackNavigator({
    Fav: {
        screen: PostsFavScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null,
        }
    },  
    Post: { // Single post screen
        screen: PostDetailsScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            title: navigation.state.params.postDetails.title,
        })
    },
});

export const TabsNavigation = TabNavigator({
    Home: { // List of posts tab
        screen: Navigation,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'POSTS',
        }
    },
    Fav: { // List of all favourite posts tab
        screen: FavNavigation,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'FAVOURITES',
        }
    }   
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work. I just had to add `navigationOptions: {header: null}` because it was showing the header twice on Favs.